# issue with stash applying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, git-stash

I am working on a rails application with another colleague. Whenever I pulled, I had encountered merge conflicts message. So each time I had seen that, I had used

```
git stash
```

and now I want to apply the changes inside those stashes, but I have problems. What I do is as follows. First I use

```
git stash list
```

to see the list of stashes. It shows that there are 4 stashes, called

```
stash@{0}
stash@{1}
stash@{2}
stash@{3}
```

My understanding is that the oldest stash is stash@{3}. So I use

```
git stash apply stash@{3}
```

I see the following messages:

```
app/helpers/application_helper.rb: needs merge
db/schema.rb: needs merge
unable to refresh index
```

But when I look into `application_helper.rb` and `schema.rb` to resolve the merge conflicts, there is no `<<<<<<` sign. The same thing happens with other stashes.

I don't know what I should do. Could you please help on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this command:

```
git fetch origin
```

This will update your local indexes with the git repo indexes.

If this doesn't resolve the issue may be the previous pull or stash has caused conflicts which you have fixed already or you have any local changes in the same files. Now until you commit the fixed file it won't allow you to pull new code. So just try and commit the files and then try applying stash again.
But check throughly the files for conflicts. Never push them to server. Hope this helps.